Sobre o plural com "quem" ou "que", qual a forma correcta?
"Eu gostei, quem não gostou foram eles"
"Eu gostei, quem não gostaram foram eles"
O "quem" é um pronome relativo invariável, então eu sempre fico na dúvida quando ele se refere a um plural. Acho que de qualquer forma o verbo ir vai para plural, mas o verbo gostar deveria estar no singular ou no plural neste caso?

A concordância com quem é no singular: quem não gostou foram eles. Na oração matriz, o verbo ser tende a ir para o plural quando liga de forma identificacional dois sintagmas nominais de números diferentes, embora as regras não sejam simples ou completamente pacíficas (há quem defenda que a concordância se faz sempre com o sujeito, aqui claramente "eles"). Daí "foram" e não "foi".
Com que o verbo iria para o plural: Foram eles que não gostaram.

Quem não gosta disso é ele. Quem não gosta disso são eles.  Ou É ele quem não gosta disso. São eles quem não gostam disso. Pode ser plural ou singular.

@Lambie são eles quem não gostam disso é agramatical

Acho que não.  Foram eles quem bateram a […] https://blogs.correiobraziliense.com.br/dad/tag/fomos-nos-quem/

@Lambie enfim, controverso: http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/minigramatica/mini/aconcordanciaeopronomequem.htm . Em todo o caso, isso só se aplicaria se quem tivesse antecedente. No caso do OP, é um quem sem antecedente (relativa livre), por isso seria sempre no singular.
